# Network Traffic Analyser using Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, shell, ping, nmap

Is there any way or script that could ping and fetch the ttl simultaneously and store in two columns in a text file for a set of IP addresses that are alive on network- I wish to make a shell script that could help me make a load balance graph.
Had tried with nmap and dig and fping command but couldn't get the desired output as asked.
Working on CentOs 6.5

Answer (score 0):

This simple script might do the job for you, if I have understood the question that is.

```
#!/bin/sh

# List of IP or domain names
LIST="192.168.1.101 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.254 192.168.1.250"

# Where to store the data?
outFile="${HOME}/network-test"

# raw data per IP
raw=""

# Clear the result each time or not? This will clear it each time
echo -n > "${outFile}"

for ip in $LIST
do
    raw=`ping -c 1 -t 255 "${ip}" | grep ttl | awk -F" |ttl=" '{ print $1 }'`
    if [ "$raw" != "" ]
    then
        echo "${ip} ${raw}" >> $outFile
    else
        echo "${ip} no-ping" >> $outFile
    fi
done

cat $outFile

exit
```

The display would be something like:

```
192.168.1.101 64
192.168.1.110 64
192.168.1.254 64
192.168.1.250 no-ping
```

Comment: You just made my day brother @Tigger Thanks...

Comment: @PranjalGupta - Happy to have helped.

Comment: Hye @Tigger, I am getting 64 as output i.e. from "64 bytes of data........." part of ping query since **when I pinged the required IP with 2 packets the TTL was 127 and not 64** but the script you provided yield 64 as an answer which I think is 64 from "64 bytes of data...." part

Comment: @PranjalGupta You need to do some research in to TTL. From [Time to live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) (wikipedia) _A recommended initial value is 64_ and also check this SuperUser Q&A [what's the meaning of TTL=64?](https://superuser.com/questions/103992/whats-the-meaning-of-ttl-64).